# Use DXValidationProvider to validate value against collection of values

Tags: c#, validation, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I want to use `DXValidationProvider` to check if `Item`'s name inside `TextEdit` is unique. I've got collection of `Item` objects available.

Pseudo code for Item class:

```
class Item {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    // ...
}
```

First I create `ConditionValidationRule`:

```
List<Item> MyItems;
// .... MyItems is filled somewhere there. Its size is >0 for sure (checked with debugger).
// Binding works for sure too.
ConditionValidationRule uniqueItemNameRule = new ConditionValidationRule();
uniqueItemNameRule.CaseSensitive = false;
uniqueItemNameRule.ConditionOperator = ConditionOperator.NotAnyOf;
uniqueItemNameRule.ErrorText = "Name must be unique";
uniqueItemNameRule.ErrorType = ErrorType.Critical;
uniqueItemNameRule.Value1 = MyItems.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
validationProvider.SetValidationRule(teName, uniqueItemNameRule);
```

However when I set Item's name which is not unique, validation passes anyway. I did not forget to perform the validation since other rules works as intended. DevExpress lacks documentation on validation rules so can't really have reading there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `ConditionOperator.NotAnyOf` you must use `ConditionValidationRule.Values` property instead of `ConditionValidationRule.Value1` property.
Here is example:

```
uniqueItemNameRule.Values.AddRange(MyItems.Select(x => x.Name).ToList());
```